# Link of 'react-router-dom' not acting as links

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `Link` in my Footer.js, and for some reason, it's not working as links in the browser. Like not showing up a pointer on the link etc. I have multiple Links in my `Nav` component. They all are working fine, but if I place a `Link` in any other component, it doesn't work. I have tried using `BrowserRouter` instead of `HashRouter` and `NavLink` instead of `Link,` but the problem still exists. It seems like a reckless mistake, though.

For now, I have this as a static website. That's why I haven't wrapped my components in `Switch` and `Route.`

Footer.js

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
             <h1>Create group!</h1>
             <Link to="/" className="rounded">Get Started</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Footer
```

App.js:

```
import Footer from './Footer'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  return (
   
    <HashRouter basename="/">
        <Nav />
        <Home />
        <About />
        <HowItWorks />
        <GroupCarousel />
        <EventCarousel />
        <Footer />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it working? Like, when you click it, does it go to a different page?

Comment: @iagowp I haven't defined any path so it won't go anywhere but it's not transforming into `Link` like not showing up a pointer on the cursor.

Comment: Have you checked the html? Maybe this is simply a css problem

Comment: @iagowp Yes, I have checked the HTML over there. It's rendering `<a>`. I have also tried applying CSS styles, but still, the problem exists. I have `Links` in the `Nav` component, and all are working fine. And other than that anywhere in the component they are not working.

Comment: Your problem seems pretty much like a css problem, not a react-router problem. Check the styles being applied to both components

Comment: @iagowp I already checked but no luck. Can you try this similar code at your workspace?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem! In my case, I'm using Material UI. Did you find any solution?  If you found, please add to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your routes inside `HashRouter` using `Switch` and `Route` tags which is to be used inside the app. Otherwise your routes won't work. Try following code and it will work as expected.

`Footer.js`

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
             <h1>Create group!</h1>
             <Link to="/" className="rounded">Get Started</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Footer
```

`App.js`

```
import Footer from './Footer'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  return (
   
    <HashRouter basename="/">
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
...

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav />
            <Home />
            <About />
            <HowItWorks />
            <GroupCarousel />
            <EventCarousel />
            <Footer />
        </>
    ):
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Nimna, I tried your solution as well, but still, I can't get to make `Link` work.